# How can I have mods on LAN and realms servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I want to do a play through and we can't play LAN but maybe but if we have the same exact stuff can we use mods on realms servers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install mods on realms.

However, if the mods are relatively simple (IE: stop endermen from picking up blocks), there *might* be a way to achieve similar things with command blocks. Otherwise, you're stuck with 3rd party hosting.